How can I force PictureBoxes to load at the same time after changing their properties?
I have a program which needs to move many images down at the same time, but the PictureBoxes load in from left to right after having their height increased, which is fairly noticeable.
for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
{
    if (Controls[i].Tag != null)
    {
        Controls[i].Location = new Point(Controls[i].Location.X, Controls[i].Location.Y + 15);
    }
}

How can I force the program to load all images at once after the for loop, instead of one at a time? I've tried using WaitOnLoad = true; and SuspendLayout(); ....... ResumeLayout(false);, but neither of these fully negated the issue, as the leftmost pictureBoxes were always slightly further down than the rightmost ones.

See my WM_SETREDRAW answer here. Basically your turn off painting, update all the controls, then turn painting back on.
